# Is the shard operation on Tensorflow Datasets deterministic?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Tensorflow Datasets have a `shard` operation that creates a unique subset of a given Dataset.

We can use it to partition a Dataset, as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
source_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(100)

number_of_partitions = 4
subset_one = source_dataset.shard(number_of_partitions, 0)
subset_two = source_dataset.shard(number_of_partitions, 1)
subset_three = source_dataset.shard(number_of_partitions, 2)
```

Is this partitioning deterministic?
i.e. the 3 subsets above would always be given the same elements?

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shard) states the following about `shard`:

> Creates a Dataset that includes only 1/num_shards of this dataset.
>
> This dataset operator is very useful when running distributed
>   training, as it allows each worker to read a unique subset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. This is a deterministic operation.

In your example above, `subset_one` contains the first element, the fifth element, etc. (`[0,4,8, ...]`) whereas `subset_two` contains `[1,5,9, ...]` and so on.